# AngularJS. Initialize controller with different data

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm using `$routeProvider` for routing in my Angular app. And for 2 routes I'm using same HTML template and same Controller.

```
        when('/products, {
            templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductListCtrl'
        }).
        when('/myProducts', {
            templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductListCtrl'
        }).
```

Only difference in data that I want to show. I.e. for path `products` I want AJAX request to `myserver:8080/products` and for for path `myProducts` I want to load data from AJAX request to `myserver:8080/products/my`.

For now I i'm using `$location` service to distinguish the current page (`products` or `myProducts`) and load apropriate data.

Is there some more elegant way to do it? For example using `resolve` method of `$routeProvider`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to reuse controller name in today scenario is to use resolve with $routeparams.

You can modify your code as below

```
 when('/products, {
                templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
                controller: 'ProductListCtrl',
    resolve: {
            product: function($http) {
              return $http.get('/products')
            },
              needToShowFilter:function($q){
               var showfilter = $q.defer();
                   showfilter.resolve(false);
               return showfilter.promise
            }
          }
            }).
            when('/myProducts', {
                templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
                controller: 'ProductListCtrl',
    resolve: {
            product: function($http) {
              return $http.get('/products/my')
            },
            needToShowFilter:function($q){
               var showfilter = $q.defer();
                   showfilter.resolve(true);
               return showfilter.promise
            }
          }
            }).
```

And then in your controller you can inject the product  into the controller code.

Comment: thank you. But can I also inject a little bit more variables? For example I also want variable `needToShowFilter`, and if its `products` then this variable should be `true` othervise `false`

Comment: You can create additional resolve property in the routes as i have created above and then you can inject the same into the controller

Answer (score 0):

try to add $route in your controller, and log

```
$route.current
```

to see what you have inside, i think thats the way to get the information